# How to Launch WPF App from a Winforms App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

How would one bring a WPF solution into a WinForms solution, and launch the WPF app inside of a WinForms window?

To clarify, I have an existing WinForms solution. I would like to bring a separate WPF solution into this solution (it is a Caliburn Micro solution, FWIW) and start it in a window from the WinForms solution. I don't want to run the compiled .exe, I want to bring the solution into the winforms solution. Can it be done?

Comment: Are you talking about wanting to combine a winforms project with a wpf project in the same solution and then host a wpf control in a winforms form? If so, here's a link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms

Comment: Are you looking to Launch a WPF from a WinForms application or are you looking embed a WPF control within a WinForms application?

Comment: If you just want to "run" the wpf application, you should use "Process" to do it, it's very easy. As for referencing projects - you just need to refer to another project as if you were referring to the library in the solution. After compiling the output, both their "exe" files are will appear in the output directory.

Comment: I have further clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article you can read here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms

Essentially it amounts to creating your WPF application as a WPF User Control Library, which will build into a DLL that you can then reference in your Windows Forms project.

You may need to refactor some of your WPF application logic so it is initialised as part of the `UserControl`, e.g., ViewModels, if you are using the MVVM design pattern.